# installing older R packages

Tags: r

I am having trouble installing some older R packages, I am using the following commands

> > require(devtools) 
> >     Loading required package: devtools 
> >     install_version("party", version = "1.0.25", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

Error in as.POSIXct.default(value) :    do not know how to convert 'value' to class “POSIXct”

Does anyone know what this error means?

Comment: I get `Error in install_version("party", version = "1.0.25", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org") : version '1.0.25' is invalid for package 'party'`

Comment: if I use a dash instead of the second period in the package version it works (`install_version("party", version = "1.0-25", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`)  (R 3.4.0 on MacOS)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package `groundhog` to install older versions of CRAN packages. Like this:

```
library('groundhog')
groundhog.library(<pkg>, <date>)
```

groundhog will also install all dependencies for the requested package as available on that date, and if a different version of R was available at the time, tell you which version will give you the fastest install time and highest likelihood of succesfully using the older package version.

Learn more at http://groundhogr.com